# Why date().getMonth() return wrong month

Tags: javascript, date

I need to get the current date from the browser for my app,
when I am calling `new Date().getMonth()` In google chrome console it shows me'9' like this :
[image: screenshots console]

Why happen this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The months in JavaScript are zero indexed, so January is 0 and December is 11. That makes October 9.

Answer (score 0):

Date.getMonth() gives one less the actual month. If you want to show proper month, define an array like 'var month=[Januaary,february....]' this, then access the month like this month[Date().getMonth()].